# Nuget: Version dependency in a tree

Tags: nuget, nuget-spec

I'm creating a Nuget package, let's call it A.

A is dependent on B version 4.3 [4.3.0,4.4).

B is dependent on C version 4.0 [4.0.0,4.1).

A is dependent on a slightly later version of C [4.0.8,4.1).

When package A builds, it identifies that B brings a dependency on C, and decides not to enforce the dependency on the latest release of C. So when I pull A into a product, it brings C version 4.0.0 from the  repository.

Is there any way to enforce the dependency between A and the higher version of C?

*I get that we're not really doing versioning well here. But assume that we can't fix that immediately.*